# Why was my Yougioh question deleted?

Tags: support, questions

I just want to know so I should know what to change.

Comment: do you have a link and/or screenshot? while there are some of us who could view your deleted question, without a link aside for yourself i believe only Mods can find it

Comment: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46198/which-anime-episodes-of-yu-gi-oh-duel-monsters-and-yu-gi-oh-gx-correspond-to-whi

Comment: ummm, that's not deleted

Comment: It isn't but it was before and I want to know what to change so it's more acceptable and won't be deleted.

Comment: after reading the comments you are talking about another question you asked just like the one you linked to but it was deleted, and you want to know why that one was deleted, correct?

Comment: Yes. I do not know.

Comment: well without a link to the actual deleted question i can't do some preliminary analysis as to how/why it would have been deleted. might have to wait for one of the Mods, if they can, to track down the question

Comment: Also are my questions forgotten? Because I haven't gotten any responses for months.

Comment: i wouldn't say forgotten but more that no one has found/compiled an answer since all your questions thus far as been anime to manga comparisons which required understanding of both

Comment: Well would you know the best users to answer them?

Comment: Yu-Gi-Oh! not Yougioh

Answer (score 8):

So [I found your deleted question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/44343/which-anime-episodes-of-yu-gi-oh-duel-monsters-and-yu-gi-oh-gx-correspond-to-whi), and as you can see, it was removed as being a dead question.

If a question has low activity, hasn't had any votes or answers to boot, and is not regularly viewed, it will be automatically deleted by [Roomba](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)

[image]

Now looking at your questions, you seem to have a lot of questions asking for Which episode of X corresponds to which manga chapter. All though the question it self is not bad, as can be seen from the views, not a lot of other people wondered about the same.

> Also are my questions forgotten? Because I haven't gotten any responses for months

People give answers because they want to, or because they are interested in the topic itself. The questions you asked, would require a lot of research and effort, which people did seem to want to take.

Now, how would  you still be able to get answers then? You could either get peoples attention and interest through the use of bounties. Or transform your question to be less research intensive.

So instead of asking : `Which anime episodes of Yu-Gi-Oh Duel Monsters and Yu-Gi-Oh GX correspond to which manga chapters?`
you could instead ask: `Which anime episodes of Yu-Gi-Oh duel monsters are canon`

This would be asking almost the same, and would require a lot less effort to figure out for the answering side.

And you can always ask the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=anime.stackexchange.com) for their opinions/improvement points ;)